# Launch Tensorboard with keras graph (for visualize accuracy, loss and predict result)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I don't understand how to use tensor board to visualize the training step of my keras network.

I already launch tensor board with the command line : `tensorboard --logdir=/run1`
But he raise this error :

> No dashboards are active for the current data set. Probable causes:You
>   haven’t written any data to your event files. TensorBoard can’t find
>   your event files.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# Create the array of data

train_data = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0]]
train_data_np = np.asarray(train_data)

train_label = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

train_label_np = np.asarray(train_data)

### Build the model

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(3,input_shape =(3,2)),
    keras.layers.Dense(3,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

  model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

#Train the model

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="run1")
model.fit(train_data_np,train_label_np,epochs=10,callbacks=tensorboard)

#test the model
restest = model.evaluate(test_data_np,test_label_np)
```

Comment: It might be because of the tensorboard command, can you try `tensorboard --logdir=run1` ? I think the slash makes it look for an incorrect folder name

Comment: Yes, it was that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding formal answer here; looks like there is a typo in the tensorboard logdir parameter. You need to remove the slash at the beginning of the directory

`tensorboard --logdir=run1`